# Why does my provider load the data twice?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, promise, angular-services

I currently follow a tutorial for a Ionic app which displays National Parks on screen. The data is stored in a local file and is loaded by my Provider, but the Provider loads the data twice. I want to load the data at startup in `app.component.ts` and then when the page loads (`park-list.ts`) it should just get the already loaded data, but the provider loads the data twice, even if I got an if-condition in my `load()` method. (It logs "DOWNLOADING" twice)

**Provider: park-data.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ParkData {

  data: any = null;

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello ParkData Provider');
  }

  load() {
    if (this.data) {
      return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.http.get("assets/data/data.json")
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
          console.log("DOWNLOADING");
          this.data = data;
          resolve(this.data);
        })
    });
  }

  getParkData() {
    return this.load().then((data) => { return data });
  }

}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import { ParkData } from "../providers/park-data";


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html',
  providers: [ParkData]
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage = TabsPage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, public parkData: ParkData) {
    console.log(parkData);
   platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
    this.parkData.load();

  }
```

**park-list.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import { ParkData } from "../../providers/park-data";
import { ParkDetails } from "../park-details/park-details";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-park-list',
  templateUrl: 'park-list.html'
})
export class ParkListPage {

  parks: Array<Object> = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public parkData: ParkData) {
      this.parkData.getParkData().then(data => this.parks = data);
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ParkListPage');
  }

  openParkDetails(park): void {
    this.navCtrl.push(ParkDetails, {parkData: park});
  }

}
```

When i put `this.parkData.getParkData().then(data => this.parks = data);` in a `setTimout` function then my Provider only "downloads" the data once. Is it because the `parkData.load()` and `parkData.getParkData()` are being called so fast one after another that the `data`  property in my provider stays `null` ?
I hope you can help me with this issue.

Comment: Note that you can use `toPromise` to convert observables to promises with a little less faff, or just *use observables*. Also note that `if (this.data) {` only tells you whether another call has *succeeded*, not whether it has *started*.

Comment: if you want the data to be loaded (cached) in your service, why not call `load` in the service constructor? also, is this component `page-park-list` in the html twice?

Comment: you can use `skipUntil()` operator

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. @AhmedMusallam It is in the html only once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're caching the data and not the promise - that's a very common mistake.

Your code is susceptible to a race condition where two requests for the data (before the data was received) can received - and trigger two different http requests.

- `load()` is called, `this.data` is not set, a promise is created.
- `load()` is called again, `this.data` is not set, a promise is created.
- first promise resolves, setting `this.data`
- second promise resolves, setting `this.data` again.

You can fix this by caching the promise and not the data:

```
export class ParkData {

  data: Promise<any> = null;

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello ParkData Provider');
  }

  load() {
    if (this.data) {
      return this.data;
    }
    return this.data = this.http.get("/assets/data/data.json").toPromise();
  }


 getParkData() {
    return this.load().then((data) => { return data });
  }

}
```